# Quasicompact over affine scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme and $f : X \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\, A$ a quasicompact morphism. Are there any easy conditions on $A$ under which we can say that $X$ is quasicompact?

Quasicompact morphism means only that there is an affine cover $\cup_{i \in I} \mathrm{Spec}\, A_i$ where $f^{-1}(\mathrm{Spec}\, A_i)$ is quasicompact. It doesn't seem to be enough.

Comment: No, it doesn't "only" mean what you say! The *correct* definition of quasi compact is that the inverse image of every open quasi-compact subset (affine or not) is quasi-compact. *Correct* means as decreed by Grothendieck in His infinite wisdom: [EGA I](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/feuilleter?id=PMIHES_1960__4_) Chap.I, Définition 6.6.1, page 152. That heresiarchs,  dissenters, renegades and apostates replace that definition by some sufficient condition  like the one you quote will in no way attenuate the torments they will suffer in the Seventh Circle of the Hell of Algebraic Geometry.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Sorry, I didn't know - my definition is from Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry

Comment: Dear NotfromBrazil: don't worry , my comment was just a  joke: no algebraic geometer was tormented while I made it! Just below the official definition, Grothendieck gives a criterion in the spirit of Hartsorne's  definition for checking quasi-compacness. You can also look at Görtz-Wedhorn's *Algebraic Geometry I* Prop. 10.1, page 242 and  on the same page at Remark 10.2 (1), which answers your question.

Comment: Hartshorne's book is full of ad hoc definitions and constructions, which are - in most cases - not the best and most transparent ones. They only work *somehow* within the context he developes. The chapters about sheaves and divisors are just a mess. Nowadays there are a lot of better introductory books to algebraic geometry. Using and quoting Hartshorne is just a habit, because decades ago this was the best book around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X$ is always quasi-compact. This is a standard result which can be found in any good and complete introduction to algebraic geometry. But you can also prove it yourself. In the end, it is just an exercise in general topology. Hint: Affines schemes are quasi-compact. So choose a finite subcover of $\{\mathrm{Spec} A_i \to \mathrm{Spec} A\}$ and observe that $X$ is a finite union of quasi-compact open subspaces.

Comment: Yes, I understand this - thank you for your answer!